# Hover not working after returning from inner page to homepage

Tags: reactjs

**It might sound weird but when i go to inner page from homepage i the hover on link hover effect works fine and goes to innerpage. then in innerpage I have a back button which returns back to Homepage and after coming back to Homepage, when I hover on the link, no Hover effect.**

this is how i have called the inner pages, if it helps

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch , Route , BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Training from './section/training';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="main homepage">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/training" component={Training} exact={true} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

## Update

This is a part of **main_content.js** in which i have used `<Link>`

```
<div className="portfolio-grid-img">
  <Link to="/training">
    <img src={training_thumb} alt="Training thumbnail" />
    <div className="portfolio-grid-overlay">
      <h3>Site Revamp</h3>
      <p>Training Terminal</p>
    </div>
  </Link>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a route to your home page component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch , Route , BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Training from './section/training';
import Home from './homePageContent';


function App() {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <Route path="/training" component={Training} exact={true} />
          </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to post that i have that in my other file actually, let me update

Comment: ok i have updated you need to set the Route for the Home/Main page content component in your switch